# Telegram login widget broken with cross site cookies disabled

Tags: authentication, browser, telegram, tracking, cross-site

Not so long ago most browsers banned third-party cookies, which broke my Telegram user authorisation flow. For example, with `Prevent cross-site tracking` option enabled (by default), after authorising the login in Telegram window nothing happens on my site (the request to telegram OAuth fails with `NOT_AUTHORIZED` reason). Turning off cross-site tracking in my browser works, but it's non-trivial for my site's visitors.

Is there any possible way to overcome with issue with Telegram login widget on newer browsers?

Comment: Same issue for me unfortunately not seen a fix yet

Comment: Yeah got reports of the login widget not working for my users as well. Out of curiosity, are you using the 'redirect to url' option of the widget or the callback function?

Comment: @Skowt I’m using redirect to url, but I’ve tried the callback as well with the same result

Comment: Got it. There's a few comments on the example code that Telegram has on their core login site and on twitter so it looks like this started breaking overnight.

Comment: Same problem for me. I'm not sure if Telegram know this issue.

Comment: @MarcoConcas I did tweet them and they said they made some changes but I still haven't had any luck getting it to work.

Answer (score -1):

```
<script async src="https://telegram.org/js/telegram-widget.js?15" 
              data-telegram-login="Anonymousairiv3Bot" 
              data-size="large" 
              data-onauth="onTelegramAuth(user)" 
              data-request-access="write">
</script>

<script type="text/javascript">
   function onTelegramAuth(user) {
      alert('Logged in as ' + user.first_name + ' ' + user.last_name + ' (' + user.id + (user.username ? ', @' + user.username : '') + ')');
   }
</script>
```

Comment: Welocme to StackOverflow! This answer could really use a nice brief description of why this is working.

Comment: This is just the normal approach I dont think it works